# How to interplet the glimpse timeline

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, glimpse

I´m trying to use Glimpse to profile my ASP .NET MVC 5.0 application. I could not find out what  the events that appear in the timeline represent.  I´m also using the EF Glimpse plugin.

I understand some events:

- The controller Event is the parent of all the stuff in my controller.
- The connetion  and Command) are the database queries and data reader 
  execution times.

But some things I do not understand:

- What is the Action result event ? It takes a lot of time and I do not know what it is.

[image]

- Why the render event has all these
  chilren? Is it the time for each HTML helper  in my view ?

[image: The render evend and its children]

And most important, how do I map each event to the part of my code it represents ?